# "Cannot read property 'set' of undefined" when using ionic storage's clear() and remove() functions

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, local-storage

I am trying to create a simple login and logout system for my project in which once I log in, the details are stored in the local storage using the "@ionic/storage" library and these details are then retrieved when initializing and used when the app is running.

Everything works fine but when I click the "contact icon" (logout button in my case => refer the screenshots attached below) the error pops up

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined"

. I am a newbie to ionic 2 and angular 2 development and I am not being able to solve this problem! I hope the info about the problem is enough and looking forward to a solution. Thank you in Advance!

The **home.ts** file looks like this.

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import { FirebaseService } from '../../services/firebase.service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Lot } from '../../classes/lot'
import { Handler } from '../../classes/handler';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  //variable to track the app state
  appState: string = "default";
  loginError: boolean = false;

  login: boolean = false;
  logout: boolean = false;

  //active variables
  activeLotKey: string;
  activeLot: Lot;

  //lots variable that contains a list of parking lots in that area
  handlers: Handler[];
  handler: Handler;

  //constructor function => initializes the lots variable
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, public _fs: FirebaseService, public storage: Storage) {
    this._fs.getHandlers().subscribe(handlers => this.handlers = handlers);
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      storage.ready().then(() => {
        storage.get('handler').then((handler) => {
          if(handler){ 
            this.handler = handler;
            console.log(this.handler);
            this._fs.getLot(this.handler.lotKey).subscribe(lot => {
              this.activeLot = lot[0];
              console.log(this.activeLot); 
            });
            //console.log(this.lot);
          } else {
            this.appState = 'login';
            console.log('chaning state to ' + this.appState);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  logIn(username: string, password: string){
    for(let handler of this.handlers){
      if(handler.username == username && handler.password == password){
        console.log("Username : " + username + " and Password " + password + " is correct...");
        this.handler = handler;
        this.handler.isLoggedIn = true;
        this._fs.updateHandler(this.handler.$key, this.handler);
        this.loginError = false;
        this.setHandler();
        this.getHandler();
        return;
      }
    }
    console.log("Username : " + username + " and Password " + password + " is incorrect!!!");
    this.loginError = true;
  }

  logOut(){
    this.handler.isLoggedIn = false;
    this._fs.updateHandler(this.handler.$key, this.handler);
    this.removeHandler();
    this.getHandler();
  }

  setHandler(){
    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
      this.storage.set("handler", this.handler).then((d) => {
        console.log("the handler is written to local storage", d);
      }, (e) => {
        console.log("Error while inserting ", e);
      });
    });
  }

  getHandler(){
    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
      this.storage.get('handler').then((handler) => {
        if(handler){
          this.handler = handler;
          console.log('get storage function' + handler);
          this._fs.getLot(handler.lotKey).subscribe(lot => {
            this.activeLot = lot[0];
            console.log(this.activeLot); 
          });
          this.appState = 'default';
          console.log('Changing appState to default');
        } else {
          this.appState = 'login';
          console.log('chaning state to ' + this.appState);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  removeHandler(){
    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
      this.storage.clear().then((d) => {
        console.log("the handler is removed from the local storage", d);
      }, (e) => {
        console.log("Error while removing ", e);
      });
    });
  }

  changeState(state: string, lot?: Lot){
    if(lot){
      this.activeLot = lot;
      this.activeLotKey = lot.$key;
    }
    console.log('changing state from ' + this.appState + ' to ' + state);
    this.appState = state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is `clear()`.

> Clear the entire key value store. WARNING: HOT!

When you use `clear()` then there is no `handler` to `get`.So you need to use `remove(key)` instead.

Please see the [**doc here about clear()**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/#clear).

Comment: I already tried using "remove(key)" and I got the same error.

Comment: I updated my post with a git link to my code. Thank you in advance.